# Open Google Maps info window on click outside map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I understand how addListener works within the map itself, but how can I get an info window to open up when I click an element outside the map? For instance, a div with the id #test?

Answer (score -1):

Attach an event listener to the element you click on. E.g. with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$("#test").click(function(){
   yourInfoWindow.open(yourMap);
});
```

You need references to the infoWindow you want to open and to the Google Maps map object. Have a look at the [API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) and the [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html).